# git credentials cache fails on windows 7

Tags: git, cygwin, credentials, git-bash

## In a nutshell

**Expected**: After using [git credentials cache](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache), I will be prompted to enter password only once.
**Actual**: I was prompted each pull for password.

## Details

I am using Windows 7 Pro., git 1.9.4 and git-extensions 2.48.03.

I am trying to cache git credentials typing

```
git config credential.helper cache
```

it tried it in both Cygwin and git-extensions bash terminal (ctrl+G in git extensions)
in both cases I was promped for password each time I pulled.

I copy from the the console:

```
$ git config --global credential.helper cache
$ git pull
<git local repo>'s password:
Already up-to-date.

$ git pull
<git local repo>'s password:
Already up-to-date.

$ cat ~/.gitconfig
 [merge]
        tool = kdiff3
 [mergetool "kdiff3"]
        path = C:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
 [diff]
        guitool = kdiff3
 [difftool "kdiff3"]
        path = C:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
 [core]
        editor = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe\" fileeditor
        autocrlf = True
 [credential]
        helper = cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using wincred on windows 7 pro.
It works for me.

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

See more on https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

Comment: I tried this on the windows server 2012:

* In Git Extension (Settings -> SSH -> Configure Git credential helper).

* In windows power shell.

* In git-extension bash window.


In all cases git keeps asking me for my password when I try to pull.

Comment: see documentation https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-all

Comment: maybe it was not clear from the qeustion: this is exaclty what i did, but it did not cache my credential, and i had to manually enter my credintials each time i pulled